# Remove items from array in local storage, when changing state

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

In my react app, I'm storing an array in local storage. When I refresh the page (or go between pages), local storage is keeping the array like it should.

However, I also want to be able to remove items from the array (and it works) but when I refresh the page, the items come back into view because I'm not removing them from local storage.

I tried removing the array from local storage, then adding the modified array back in storage, but it's not working either.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ls from "local-storage";
function HomeIndex() {
  const [diePool, setDiePool] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setDiePool(ls("diePoolArray") || []);
    setPoolCount(ls("poolCount") || 1);
  }, []);
  //WORKS**
  const addToPool = () => {
    ls("diePoolArray", [
        ...diePool,
        { 
        dp1 : poolCount,
        dp2 : diceType,
        dp3 : diceNumber,
        dp4 : diceAdjuster,
        dp5 : diceAlias,
        dp6 : poolStatus
        }
    ]);
    setDiePool(ls("diePoolArray"));
    var tempPoolCount = poolCount;
    tempPoolCount++;
    setPoolCount(tempPoolCount);
    ls("poolCount", tempPoolCount)
    clearState();
  };
  //DOESNT WORK**
  const handleRemoveItem = die => {
    setDiePool(diePool.filter(diePool => diePool.dp1 !== die.dp1));
    //Reset the local storage for the die pool
    ls.remove("diePoolArray");
    ls("diePoolArray", diePool);
    //setTestArray(ls("testArray"));
    //
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At `handleRemoveItem` note that your not modifying `diePool`, instead you are creating a new array using `filter` and then calling `setState` to modify it.

The problem with this, is that **the changes of a setState call are not immediately applied**, so the reference of `diePool` does not necessarily contains the new value you are trying to set.

What you should do is first create a new array and than update State and Local Storage

```js
let newArray = diePool.filter(diePool => diePool.dp1 !== die.dp1);
setState(newArray);
ls("diePoolArray", newArray);
```

Comment: I changed your code above to `setDiePool(newArray);` and it worked as it should.